# Override Spaces: How to span an application(Citrix Workspace) full-screen on 2 of 4 monitors in OSX Catalina?

Tags: catalina, spaces

I have a four monitor setup at home (2 large, 2 small). Is there a way to give Citrix access to only two monitors in full-screen mode? It seems to be stuck between all-monitors or one-monitor...

Or if I could merge two spaces and keep the other monitors separate?